# How to reload data when using useFuture flutter hook

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hooks

I'm using Flutter hooks to fetch data by combining useMemorized and useFuture like this:

```
final _latestDocsFuture =
    useMemoized(() => getLatestDocs());
final _latesetDocsSnapshot = useFuture(_latestDocsFuture);
```

The problem with this hook is I can't re-trigger the useFuture to re-fetch the data in case of an error (allowing the user to tap on a button to try and fetch the data again).
Is there any method that can let me re-trigger the useFuture hook?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `useMemoized` hook accepts a list of keys that can be used to create new instances of the Future, which would cause `useFuture` to run again.

I'd suggest using the `UniqueKey` class to achieve this

```
final reloadKey = useState(UniqueKey());
final latestDocsFuture = useMemoized(() => getLatestDocs(), [reloadKey.value],);
final latestDocsSnapshot = useFuture(latestDocsFuture);
```

Then whenever you wish to reload, you can update the value of `reloadKey`

```
reloadKey.value = UniqueKey();
```